# Kafka Producer to consume csv

Tags: python, apache-kafka, producer

I am simulating a kafka producer to read from a file . I would like to read from file for every 15 minutes since file gets changed every 15 minutes.
Can I have sample python code to produce kafka topic by reading a csv ?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please your code too? We're more than happy to help you but we're missing context here, for example what you tried, CSV example, etc.

Comment: Also keep in mind that SO in not a code development service, we're more than happy to help you out if you're stuck, but nobody will do you job for free!

Comment: By the way, Kafka Connect is a built in framework to Kafka for things like this. No reason to write code yourself. Might need to know how to deploy Java apps. https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what @cricket_007 said. [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) is specifically built for ingesting data from other systems to Kafka (and, for streaming from Kafka to other systems if you want).

The connector he mentions, http://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir, will ingest CSV files for you into Kafka.